# Cannot type out new lines or do a typing effect

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to make a website that writes out strings with a typing effect. I've been able to display lines without typing them out but I cannot add a newline into them. I've also been trying to make a typing effect but it has not worked at all.

Here's the version without the typing effect:

```
function nextLineUntype(text){ 
  document.getElementById("game").innerHTML += "\n[" + lineNum +"]" + text;
  lineNum ++;
}
```

and here is the version with the typing effect:

```
function nextLine(text){
  typing(text, 50);
  lineNum ++;
}
function typing (txt, speed){
  var i = 0;
  function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("game").innerHTML += "\n[" + lineNum + "]" + txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
}
```

I use the functions like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
nextLineUntype("WIP - V.0.001");
nextLineUntype("Welcome To Saltmoss's Warriors Text Adventure!");
nextLine("Press Enter To Continue");
});
```

this is the html I'm using:

```
  <body style="background-color:black">
    <p id="game"></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="enterspace"></p>
  </body>
```

and it outputs like this:

Comment: You created the `typeWriter` function but never call it.

Comment: Use `<br>` for a newline in HTML, unless the output DIV has `write-space: pre` style.